# Unable to run after docker build ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

(Please don't beat me up if my question isn't perfect. I really have been working a long time on this and have a simple question I know one of you guys have solved and would like to get EYES on it. Please forgive my lack of perfection.)

---

Ok, so I created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I added a few layers (DAL, Service, BL, etc.) and wired everything up. API layer talks to Service layer, etc...

Running locally with Dockerfile within `/Api` (by default - the WeatherForecast project).

Finally get ready to set up my CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps and realize that my Dockerfile needs to be at the root of all my projects not within the `/Api` project. So I moved it up a layer and the Azure DevOps build started working but I am no longer able to get it to run in Visual Studio 2022. It wants the Dockerfile next to the `.csproj`.

Pushed to ACR and am not able to see my Swagger page. So I'd like to run locally. I'm able to do a `docker build --tag myTag:123 .` and this works but when I go into Visual Studio Code and try run the image I get:

> Executing task: docker run --rm -d  -p 443:443/tcp -p 80:80/tcp pa-v5:latest
> 6d55a242ad4b308abe0a4e055ae82c2345f2d365d4055c25cd06e466dbfa1fd8
>
> Docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run on your computer this command?

```
netstat -ano | find "80"
```

The port "80" probably will be associated to PID 4 which is a Windows system process that groups several services like the World Wide Web Publishing service. If you need to bind ports 80 and 443 to your docker image you will have to run this command:

```
net STOP HTTP
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergio but after I run the net STOP HTTP how to I reenable it? net START HTTP?

Comment: Yes, you can do that or just restart specific services. Did this question help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Not sure yet Sergio, I will try maybe later or over the weekend. Busy week :-)